# What favicon/icon logo would you like to have for Buddhism SE?

Tags: discussion, design

Present you idea and design one, you could use such tools like http://www.favicon.cc/ (no special skills necessary)

And! Vote for the best. (it's the makers choice of course, if they wish so, so it not my person who decides at all)

Be aware that, in the case you save it there that you are able to present it, stick to their conditions as well as it you save it here, if such is possible.

In the case you like to give it to the community here (actually to StackExchange), don't miss to express it consciously. Maybe the team here likes the idea and takes the most voted one. Maybe some would even give it a bounty.

How ever, much joy with your creative answers and generosity. Maybe you like to share even an explaining of how you thoughts have been to make it this or that way and discuss the graphic expression.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your suggestion, Bhante.

Perhaps I should tell you that we (the community of users) are unable to edit the web site's software functionality, page layout, and other style-related content. See also [Allowing CSS customization of beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254375/139866) (which was proposed to Stack Exchange but which is *not* a feature-proposal which they have accepted); and see [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/139866) (which describes what it means to be a "Beta" site, and mentions that they have a long backlog in their queue of 'style' changes).

That said, if we (the community) did choose or design a favicon, I expect that the SE designer would consider that suggestion, if or whenever this site does 'graduate', and they consider designing style customizations for this site.

---

For those who don't know, the 'favicon' which you suggest we redesign is the icon that appears in the chrome of browser tabs, or when the site appears in a bookmark, favourite, or shortcut.

The current favicon for the site is:

[favicon http://cdn.sstatic.net/buddhism/img/favicon.ico](http://cdn.sstatic.net/buddhism/img/favicon.ico)

Comment: ups... *sigh* seem to be not easy for you here, even the environment is most seductive. (no comment on the porposal and who...)

Comment: Would you mark this answer as 'accepted', if you don't mind? Because if a topic has no accepted answer then it will repeatedly, periodically, jump to the top of the 'active' view to get attention (which is useless because I don't think there's anything to add to this topic).

Comment: Correct me, Upasaka Chris, if Atma is wrong, neither the main question is answered nor do the speculations give facts. If people act simply on speculation and what they need to and what they are called to do, where is the place of Dana and merits?

Comment: If you still want people to design favicons then don't accept this answer. I don't think any user-designed favicons can used though, on this site, at least until the site 'graduates from beta'.

Answer (score 1):

If one day the site will be graduated from Beta, let the favicon be an eightfold wheel, the symbol of Dharma. Black wheel for Beta and one of Buddhist colors for the main site. Yellow may be too bright, so let it be red (Padma family) or blue (Manjushri's family color, very suitable for the Q & A site).